# How can I reuse a function properly?

Tags: javascript

I try to make 3 basic slideshow.

I made this code for the first one and wanted to use it on the other 2 as well with the New slideS() method and with some parameter changing.But it's not working,even the first function is'nt working if I put parameter in it.

Can somebody explain me why is this not working and how to fix it?Thanks beforehand!

```
var img = document.getElementById("asd");
var imgArr = ["1.jpg", "3.png", "3.png"];
var i = 0;

function slideS(a) {

  a.src = imgArr[i];

  if (i < imgArr.length - 1) {

    i++;

  } else {

    i = 0;
  }
  setTimeout("slideS()", 1500);
}
slideS(img)
```

Comment: well that code relies on global variables

Comment: What isn't working?  There are a lot of things based on this code that could be giving you unexpected results.

Comment: Describe "not working." If you're getting an error, add the error details to the question. If something unexpected is happening, explain what you expected and what it's doing instead.

Comment: *"How can I reuse a function properly?"* All dependencies should be passed as arguments.

Comment: I think the most problematic point of the function above and the solutions below is that the function relies on global variables, so the function isn't pure. That's why it can't be used easily for other slide shows.

Comment: More accurately my problem is that when I use the following code with the parameter "a" instead var img(which I declare later when calling the function)I expected to do the same thing as if I using var img,which is change the img src every 1.5 sec.But it does'nt do that.The var img has an Error that says "document not defined" and I get the same Error with setTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, using an object oriented approach:

```
function SlideShow(el, imagesArray, msDelay) {
  this.el = el;
  this.images = imagesArray;
  this.delay = (msDelay) ? msDelay : 1000;
  this.timer = null;

  this.Run = function () {
    var self = this;
    var index = 0;
    this.timer = setInterval(function(){
      self.el.src = self.images[index++ % self.images.length];
    }, this.delay);
  }

  this.Stop = function() {
    this.timer = null;
  }
}

var img = document.getElementById("asd");
var imgArr = ["1.jpg", "3.png", "3.png"];
var delay = 1500;
var ss = new SlideShow(img, imgArr, delay);
ss.Run();
...
ss.Stop();
```

Would that work for you? Then you are using pure functions and an object that can be used to start, stop, and manage any slide show.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want like:

Remove setTimeout. And use setInterval:

```
setInterval(function(){
  slideS(img)
},1500)
```

Comment: Well the slideshow is working but after the first image it's glitching out(changing really fast and not in order)

Comment: Sorry,It's working.At first it does'nt work because it was the wrong place(in the function)but then I placed it after the function and now it's functioning correctly.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure over the element and the array and use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

```js
function slide(id, array) {
    function swap() {
        image.src = array[i];
        i++;
        i %= array.length;
    }

    var image = document.getElementById(id),
        i = 0;

    setInterval(swap, 1500);
}

slide('image1', ['http://lorempixel.com/400/200/', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/']);
```

```html
<image id="image1"></image>
```

Comment: Great solution!:)

Answer (score 0):

try this... you are making mistake at some places

```
var img = document.getElementById("asd");
var imgArr = ["1.jpg", "3.png", "3.png"];
var i = 0;

function slideS(a) {

  a.src = imgArr[i];

  if (i < imgArr.length - 1) {

    i++;

  } else {

    i = 0;
  }

  setTimeout(() => slideS(a), 1500);
/* you need to pass function to setTimeout and pass refrence of image that's 'a' */

// or use function instead of arrow function

  setTimeout(function() { slides(a) }, 1500);

}
slideS(img)
```

hope this helps..

Comment: `let a = imageToPass` is unnecessary. `imageToPass` is already local. And it wouldn't matter if you used `var` or `let` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it works when the function doesn't take a parameter?

Then, the reason it would work with no parameter, but stop working with a parameter, is that the setTimeout tries to recursively call the function but doesn't pass a parameter.  So you'd change that to

```
setTimeout(() => {slideS(a);}, 1500);
```

But then when you try to run multiple instances of this concurrently, you'll get into trouble because your'e using global variables.  You'll need to use something more local (perhaps closures?) for your lcv, for example.

Comment: This one is working as well,Thank you.Another question if you don't mind:You said that when i try to use a function multiple times global variables are no good and I should use more local variables...Why is the global function not an option?I mean functions can access global variables,right?So it should work just as if I use local variables.Or i can't pass parameters to another function that way or what?Sorry if it's sound stupid!

Comment: Using global variables inside of a function is like walking into a high school classroom, giving them a bottle of water, and getting the bottle after the class and assuming there will still be water in the bottle and it will be the same amount. You have no idea what they did with it. That's why pure functions (https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976) are the preferred pattern, as I show in my answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974423/how-can-i-reuse-a-function-properly/55974603#answer-55974603

Comment: @MátéSéra - Ok, so you have your function using global variables, and you call `slideS(a)`.  It is now modifying, and depending on the values of, those global variables.  Then you also run `slideS(b)`.  It is now *also* modifying the values of those same global variables, meaning `slideS(a)` will not be able to rely on the values being as it has set them at any given time.

Comment: So the problem is that function updating the global variables,okay.I thought or rather read that that a function could change the global variable value but only keep that value in it's function scope.So you could use a changed global variable there and outside the function you could use the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead of `setTimeout`

```js
var img = document.getElementById("asd");
var imgArr = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgt0W.png", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0fKm.png", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfPSD.png"];
var i = 0;

function slideS(a) {


  a.src = imgArr[i];

  if (i < imgArr.length - 1) {

    i++;

  } else {

    i = 0;
  }
}

slideS(img);  //initial call to start it without having to wait for 1500 ms to pass

setInterval(function() {
    slideS(img);
}, 1500);
```

```html
<img id="asd">
```

[image: A]
[image: B]
[image: C]