# What is the correct way to put a HTML element into a variable?

Tags: javascript

I need this code for an automated slideshow on a page.
I have tried changing up the variables.

HTML
JavaScript

```
<img class="container" id="c1" > 
<img class="container" id="c2"> 
<img class="container" id="c3">
<p class="dot" id="d3"></p>
<p class="dot" id="d2"></p>
<p class="dot" id="d1"></p>


var i;
let slide;
let dot;

function plusSlide()
{
    for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      slide = document.getElementById("c" + i);
      dot   = document.getElementById("d" + i);

      if (i == 3)
      {
        slide.id = "c" + 0;
        dot.id   = "d" + 0;
      }
      else
      {
        slide.id = "c" + (i + 1);
        dot.id   = "d" + (i + 1);
      }
    }

  setTimeout(plusSlide, 5000);
}

plusSlide();
```

The result is correct, but at the variables it says: `Parsing Error: Unexpected Token slide`

Ok so I am using this for a slideshow with three slides, `c` are the pictures and `d` are the dots, I am taking the elements with these `ids` and I am changing them. I use `CSS` so only `#c1` is displayed.

It does work completely fine, but if i try to validate it it shows me an error message at row 2 and 3.

Comment: Are you using a JS enginer that does not support `let`?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/fitayinuhe/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem. It isn't clear which of the many instances of `slide` the error is being thrown on. You haven't said which JS engines you've tested with either.

Comment: You may want to look at a similar question I responded to here. Also, read the comments about pure functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55974603/2437278

Comment: what do u mean "put an HTML element into a variable"? can you give us an example

Comment: Could it be your eslint configuration that is messing stuff up? If you comment out this part of your code and paste it in your browser console when you have your html on the page, does it work?

Comment: @SLaks what do you mean by that?

Comment: "It does work completely fine, but if i try to validate it" — Define "validate" in this context.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well? it's quite difficult without having it.

Comment: @Quentin It doesn't output error messages, but in an online validator it shows error messages

Comment: @shadowboii__ — "an online validator" … **which** online validator?

Comment: @James — Why would the HTML help? The OP already said the code works. It's just some unspecified tool that says there is a problem.

Comment: @Quentin I think there is no issue, just the validators I used didn't use engines that support let as a variable. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Ok thanks everyone for your help, there wasn't really an issue, I'm just new to JS and didn't know something.

I used a validator, that didn't use an engine, that supports let variables.